# Normalizing TF-IDF results

Tags: normalization, normalize, tf-idf

I would like to normalize the tfidf results that I've got from this given code:

```
for (int docNum = 0; docNum < ir.numDocs(); docNum++) {
            TermFreqVector tfv = ir.getTermFreqVector(docNum, "contents");
            if (tfv == null) {
                // ignore empty fields
                continue;
            }
            String[] tterms = tfv.getTerms();
            int termCount = tterms.length;
            int[] freqs = tfv.getTermFrequencies();
            for (int t = 0; t < termCount; t++) {
                double idf = ir.numDocs() / ir.docFreq(new Term("contents", tterms[t]));
                System.out.println(" " + tterms[t] + " " + freqs[t]*Math.log(idf));
            }
        }
```

the output for this code is:

```
area 0.0
areola 5.877735781779639
ari 3.9318256327243257
art 1.6094379124341003
artifici 1.0986122886681098
assign 2.1972245773362196
associ 3.295836866004329
assur 1.9459101490553132
averag 1.0986122886681098
avoid 0.6931471805599453
.
.
.
```

Any help would be much appreciated. thank you

Comment: I would like to normalize the tfidf results that I've got from this given code:

Comment: TF-IDF **is** a normalization.

Answer (score 10):

A common approach is to normalize by document size. i.e. instead of using the **term counts** (or absolute frequencies), you use the relative frequencies.

Let `freqsum` be the sum over your frequencies array. Then use

```
freqs[t]/(double)freqsum*Math.log(idf)
```

To avoid this type of confusions, I recommend to use the terminology:

- **term counts** for the "absolute frequencies"
- **relative frequency** for the word-in-document ratio

instead of the ambiguous term "*term frequency*".

I know that historically, if you look up the Salton, Yang, On the specification of term values in automatic indexing (1973), they refer to absolute counts. Cosine similarity will be removing the scale, so there it does not matter there anyway. Modern systems like Lucene will try to control the influence of the document better.

Comment: Just to make something clear- so you mean `freqsum` according to my code above is `termCount`? I just want clarification sorry bro.

Comment: No, `termCount` is the number of *different* terms, isn't it? I'm talking about the total sum. Think of **relative term frequencies** and it should be clear.

Comment: is this correct Mr. Anony?
`int[] freqs = tfv.getTermFrequencies();`
`double freqsum = Math.sqrt(freqs[i]) / tterms.length;`

Comment: No. Computing the sum does not involve taking square root.

Comment: Couldn't that result in a negative value as well?

Comment: When would that happen?

Answer (score 0):

By "normalise" I assume you want a range between 0 and 1 for each TFIDF value.
However, how you do that normalisation depends on what you want to achieve.

One option is to find the larges tfidf value (Tmax, where T is TFIDF) in all the documents and subtract from that each TFIDF value individually and divide that result by Tmax. This is then subtracted from one in order to get a range from 0 to 1 where a higher score indicates relevance (Tnorm = 1 - (Tmax - T)/Tmax). You can skip the "subtract for one" part, but take note that lower scores will indicate a higher unnormalised TFIDF.

However, sometimes it is more convenient to normalise on a per document level, in which case you get the sum of TFIDF values within the document and divide each TFIDF with that sum. In this case the highest score still wins, depending on your use case.

On a per document level is more useful in my use cases, which involves scoring queries to identify documents. I normalise between 0 and 1 so that both TF and TFIDF are on the same scale, and multiplying two reandom scores has no risk of sometimes lowering and sometimes increasing the product when the denominator is smaller than or larger than the numerator.